# Problem on creating webmap for a online game

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am trying to create a webmap for my game based on `OpenSimulator`.

All images are present on one position (ex: https://example.com/map-1-1000-1000-objects.jpg).

Now I am trying to display these Images on my worldmap. I can implement leaflet without any problems. I think my problem is the conversion of latlng because the coordinates of my world are without any decimals (like the example above).

1000x1000 means X x Y. The first type after the "/map-" is the zoom (by default only 1). So the entire URL is: `/map-(Z)-(X)-(Y)-objects.jpg`.

How can i display these tiles with leaflet?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your tiles naming scheme directly includes your "coordinates"; therefore they do not follow the quad tree naming convention that Leaflet default Tile Layer assumes.

You can easily adapt Leaflet Tile Layer to your need by overriding the [`getTileUrl`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.5.1/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L163-L186] method.

In your developer console you will see the URL of requests that Leaflet makes, so you adjust your implementation of getTileUrl more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your tiles are accessible as you describe, then you can implement a tile layer in Leaflet like this:

```
L.tileLayer('https://example.com/map-{Z}-{X}-{Y}-objects.jpg');
```

Other options might be needed, but that should get you started.

Comment: OK peeebee. Thank you for that answer. That i knowed allready. My Problem seems to be part of the initialization. I forgot to say that i want to start at coordinate 1000x1000.